# Adherence Values of a funtion

Tags: limits

I am stuck with this:

Prove that the adherence values of the function sin(1/x)/x  at the zero point are the whole Real Numbers.

When we see the graph we are convinced of the truth, but giving a formal proof does not seem so easy. In the book I am studying, the author only makes this statement, but does not justify it and does not provide any hint.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The question probably asks: if $\delta>0$ and $y\in\mathbb{R} $ then there is an $x\in(-\delta, \delta) $ such that $y=(1/x) \sin(1/x)$. Let me know if this is the correct interpretation of adherence values used in your question.

Comment: Hello mister. My book defines adherence value of a funtion at a pont this way:

Comment: A real number ´´z´´ is called a adherence value of a function at point ´´a´´  when there is a sequence x(n) of points other than ´´a´´ such that lim x(n) = a and lim f[x(n)] = z.